# Why show error "ReferenceError: response is not defined"

Tags: angular

When I try do consume the response I am getting this error
***"ReferenceError: response is not defined"***

My Response format is

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "employeeId":2,
         "employeeCode":"e1",
         "employeeName":"Komal",
         "departmentId":1,
         "designationId":1,
         "reportingEmployeeId":1,
         "mobileNumber":"9797979797",
         "emailId":"komal@gmail.com",
         "joiningDate":"2019-09-08T00:00:00",
         "departments":null,
         "designations":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Below is my code

```
GetAllEmployee() {
    this.employeeService.getAllEmployee().subscribe((response) => this.employees = response.body.data);
  }
```

here is my front end code

```
 <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
                    <td>
                        {{employee.EmployeeCode}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.EmployeeName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.MobileNumber}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.EmailId}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{employee.JoiningDate}}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

What I am doing wrong. Please suggest me.

Comment: can you show us the log of your response so we will get better idea what went wrong

Comment: same error coming

Comment: Which line is giving you this error? Is the response provided actually the body?

Comment: Response is showing in console but binding in front end

Comment: When you display the data on the template, you need to use the *exact* names as per the response received. Eg: (`employee.employeeCode` instead of `employee.EmployeeCode`)

Answer (score 1):

I think this error can be caused by a number of reasons, you should check these:

1) Check the response from the API, for example the data returned from the request (showed in "Network" tab in Chrome, you have to click on the request and check "Response" tab), the HTTP status (maybe you are returning the data but with a wrong HTTP status).

2) Check the format of the response, this is usually JSON as you showed, but maybe it's not a valid JSON, you can check that by copying the response and linting it in https://jsonlint.com/

3) Check if the response is been parsed, sometimes the response from the API is valid, but it's not parsed to JSON (Angular does this automatically since version 5 I beleive), you can do that by wrapping the response in a JSON.parse function like this:  JSON.parse(response).

4) Angular doesn't recognize the structure of the response automatically, I usually add a typing of "any" to the response so Typescript doesn't complain about the properties of the response object, like this:  "... (response: any) => console.log(response) ...".

5) Check if function "getAllEmployee()" is returning a valid http object, from "@angular/common/http", and that it have a valid configuration (like HttpHeaders, or "withCredentials: true" if you are using authentication).

In any case, the best thing you can do is to log the response to the console and show us the content, try with this code:

```
this.employeeService.getAllEmployee()
   .subscribe(
      (response: any) => console.log(response), 
      (err) => console.error('Failed with : ', err),
      () => console.log('getAllEmployee finished...')
   );
```